# Criteria join with projection

Tags: hibernate, criteria, nhibernate-criteria

I am going to create this SQL query's `Criteria` equivalent:

SQL:

```sql
SELECT
  orders.id,
  book.title,
  orderitem.quantity

  FROM orderitem
    INNER JOIN book ON book.id = orderitem.book_id
    INNER JOIN orders ON orders.id = orderitem.orders_id

WHERE user_id = 1
```

Here is my `Criteria` query:

```
Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(OrderItem.class, "oi");
c.setProjection(Projections.property("quantity"));

c.createAlias("oi.book", "book");
c.setProjection(Projections.property("title"));
c.createAlias("oi.orders", "or");
c.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));
c.createAlias("or.user", "usr");

c.add(Restrictions.eq("usr.id", "1"));
return c.list();
```

It has no exception, but it displays just `Orders.id` column:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 22]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ProjectionList](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) . It will return Object array containing fields quantity , title , id .

```
Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(OrderItem.class, "oi");
c.createAlias("oi.book", "book");
c.createAlias("oi.orders", "or");
c.createAlias("or.user", "usr");

ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();
proList.add(Projections.property("oi.quantity"));
proList.add(Projections.property("book.title"));
proList.add(Projections.property("or.id"));
c.setProjection(proList);
c.add(Restrictions.eq("usr.id", "1"));
return c.list();
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to receive the result list as named keys & values other than index & value. I used following way.

```
Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(OrderItem.class, "oi");
c.createAlias("oi.book", "book");
c.createAlias("oi.orders", "or");
c.createAlias("or.user", "usr");

ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();
proList.add(Projections.property("oi.quantity"), "quantity");
proList.add(Projections.property("book.title"), "title");
proList.add(Projections.property("or.id"), "id");
c.setProjection(proList);

c.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);

c.add(Restrictions.eq("usr.id", "1"));
return c.list();
```